# Swipe Gesture Error in Flash CS6

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-cs6, swipe-gesture

Hey everyone so been trying to fix this and can't figure out how.

When i set up my listeners for a Swipe gesture I get this error in Flash CS6 using AIR 22.0 for Android:

> ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property velocity on runtime.simulation.TransformGestureSimEvent.

I Know the code isn't wrong. Here is how It is setup:

```
//MultiTouch added for touch gestures
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
startScreen.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe);
private function onSwipe(e:TransformGestureEvent):void 
    {
        if (e.offsetY == 1)
        {
            //Swipe towards bottom 
            startScreen.gotoAndStop(2);
            trace("Swipe down");
        }

        if (e.offsetY == -1)
        {
            //Swipe towards top
            startScreen.gotoAndStop(1);
            trace("Swipe UP");
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't unable to google neither **runtime.simulation** package nor **TransformGestureSimEvent** class. Are you sure they are not weird custom classes in your project? The code above is fine.

Comment: Yeah Neither was I. No I don't believe I do. Ill recheck and if anything else create a new Test Project and see if it works then. Thanks though Organis for helping